# How can I get my own apps onto my jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, jailbreak, development

I want to be able to test the apps I am creating on my jaikbroken iPhone 3Gs, and I want to know how I can get my apps from xCode onto my device without a developer account.

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=398#more-398) really helped me.

I'm not sure if it's still that relevant though. I remember just setting my xCode to "Don't code sign" or something similar. I can't really check it right now, I'll get back to this. Make sure you have appsync installed on your iPhone though, that is a must.

After that you might be able to run the app on the iPhone, but you won't be able to debug it live.